# Best source for understanding properties of definite integral

Tags: calculus, integration, reference-request, definite-integrals

I always get confused in properties of definite integral. Can you please share some best online sources or books for understanding definite integral. Specially, the one which have lots of problems for each property.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Being in India, the best source for understanding Integral calculus is Deepak Bharadwaj's book [Integral Calculus made easy](https://books.google.co.in/books?id=CD966TcWrQIC&printsec=frontcover&dq=understanding+properties+of+definite+integral&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwin36DjsL7YAhVGNY8KHeXpCbUQuwUIKjAC#v=onepage&q=understanding%20properties%20of%20definite%20integral&f=false).

You can also see his other book [Definite Integral made easy](https://books.google.co.in/books?id=Xsrz4IvpgnsC&printsec=frontcover&dq=understanding+properties+of+definite+integral&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwin36DjsL7YAhVGNY8KHeXpCbUQuwUIHjAA#v=onepage&q=understanding%20properties%20of%20definite%20integral&f=false).

Both are replete with examples and give a thorough understanding of the concepts.

Comment: Rohan - what is special about these books? thanks!

Comment: @samjoe When I was in school, our library had copies of these books from which teachers used to set questions. That's all. Why?

Comment: I also live in india, so I was asking :) I refer to ncert book and internet resource. What are your views on ncert

Comment: @samjoe NCERT is sufficient for boards. But, for other competitive exams like JEE, doesn't stand a chance... Always better to go apart from that if your focus is not on the boards.